# jQuery Display Textbox When an Option is Selected

Tags: jquery, html

I want to be able to display the appropriate text box when a certain value is selected. I would appreciate any help.

```
JQUERY 
$('#enterdatabox').change(function() {
var selected = $(this).val();
  $('#' + selected).css('display', selected ? 'block' : 'none');
});



HTML
<select name="enterdatabox" id="enterdatabox">
      <option value="">Please Choose...</option>
      <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
      <option value="option4">Option 4</option>
      <option value="option5">Option 5</option>
      <option value="option6">Option 6</option>
      <option value="option7">Option 7</option>
      <option value="option8">Option 8</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="option1" style="display: none;" />
<input type="text" id="option2" style="display: none;" />
<input type="text" id="option3" style="display: none;" />
<input type="text" id="option4" style="display: none;" />
<input type="text" id="option5" style="display: none;" />
<input type="text" id="option6" style="display: none;" />
<input type="text" id="option7" style="display: none;" />
<input type="text" id="option8" style="display: none;" />
```

Comment: What problem are you having? Your code seems fine: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/wKLVT/

Comment: @j08691 I think that this is the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/wKLVT/1/

Comment: @ExplosionPills, the answer you just deleted was correct. I tried all three of your solutions and they fixed the problem, which was that the text boxes weren't displaying once the appropriate option was selected. So thank you. Is there just a simplistic way to just make sure that the text boxes don't stack on each other when numerous options are selected in a row without having to hide each textbox?

Comment: @user2004710 I'll undelete my answer so you can accept it.  You will have to remove them all each time, but it's pretty simple to just do `$("input").hide()` or the like

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code is fine, but the problem is probably that you are binding `.change` before the `#enterdatabox` element exists.  There are three simple solutions:

1. Move the JavaScript code *after* the HTML
2. Wrap the JavaScript code in `$(document).ready(function () {}`
3. Use event delegation, e.g. `$(document).on('change, '#enterdatabox', function () {`

The first one is probably the easiest.

---

By the way you can probably make this code a lot simpler by removing all of the ids and wrapping the `<input>` in a div and compare using `.index()`